# get answer from mongodb in perl

Tags: mongodb, perl

I have written code to fetch answer from MongoDB in Perl but it is not working. It always gives context error. What I am trying to do is fetch result based on a search criteria in MongoDB

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MongoDB;
use Data::Dumper;

sub answer_get {
my $database = shift;
my $database_collection = shift;
my $msg = shift;
my $client = MongoDB->connect();
my $db = $client->get_database( 'tutorial' );
my $query_result = $db->get_collection( 'users' )->find({context: "what", 
keyword: "IP"},{"define":1});
}
my $get_answer = answer_get("tutorial", "users", "IP");
#print $get_answer;
```

Output

```
syntax error at mongoreply.pl line 15, near "context:"
Global symbol "$query_result" requires explicit package name (did you forget 
to declare "my $query_result"?) at mongoreply.pl line 21.
syntax error at mongoreply.pl line 25, near "}"
Execution of mongoreply.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

When I am running it in MongoDB I am getting answer

```
db.users.find({context: "what", keyword: "IP"},{"define":1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4314bda763102504004ea1"), "define" : "An Internet 
Protocol address (IP address) is a numerical label assigned to each device 
connected to a computer network that uses the Internet Protocol for 
communication" }
```

What my requirement is to get statement in define that I have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error you are getting is from perl and has nothing to do with MongoDB.
To build a hashref, you must use the following notation:

```
{
    key => value,
    other_key => other_value,
}
```

not `{ "key": "value" }` ( which looks like JSON ).